# Ignore attrib Attribute error

Tags: batch-file

How can I ignore the attribute error I get when I issue this command?

```
 attrib -r D:\deploy\A_qa\Sample1\*.* /S /D
```

I've encountered an "access denied" error issue, because I'm unable to change one file attribute.

My question is, how can I ignore it, so that the error message isn't displayed?  I've tried hiding the file, but unfortunately the error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the output so you won't see it:

```
attrib -r D:\deploy\A_qa\Sample1\*.* /S /D > nul
```